# WinMerge: how to ignore comments

Tags: comments, winmerge

I'm using WinMerge to compare java files in folders (including subfolders).
I would like to ignore comments when the comparison is done, but I don't know how to do it.

At the file level I've found a switch in the option, so if I compare two files the comments are ignored. However if I compare the folders where those two files live WinMerge tells me that the files are different. Then when I click on the files WinMerge finds out that the only differences are comments and it tells me the files are equal.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plugin IgnoreCommentsC.dll. The plugin ignores comments within //... and /* ... */ delimiters in C, C++, PHP and JavaScript files.

You could just associate it with java files. Download from [here](http://winmerge.org/downloads/plugins.php).

**EDIT**:
It seems that the link doesn't have the plugins downloadable anymore. The documentation says to install plugins at installation time. You can find more information about plugins in the documentation ([general info](http://manual.winmerge.org/Plugins.html), [available plugins](http://manual.winmerge.org/Plugins.html#Plugins_available))